# Installing GeoServer 2.23 with GDAL extensions on Ubuntu 22.04 - libgdal-java not found

Tags: gdal, ubuntu

I have installed GeoServer 2.23 on Ubuntu 22.04 and it is working fine.

I have also installed the GDAL extension. In order to get the GDAL extension to work, the manual https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/gdal.html say that I must also install

```
sudo apt-get install gdal-bin libgdal-java

gdal-bin is installed fine at version 3.4.1

libgdal-java is not found.
```

How can I install libgdal-java onto Ubuntu 22.04?
Is it present in a different repositary?